# What is causing this compile error?

Tags: apex

I get the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void
> updateAccountNumbersofContacts(List<Id>) from the type
> ContactTriggerHandler

when compiling the code below but don't see why.

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Contact> newContacts) {
        List<Id> accountIdsToUpdate = new List<Id>();
        for (Contact newContact : newContacts) {
            accountIdsToUpdate.add(newContact.AccountId);
        }

        updateAccountNumbersofContacts(accountIdsToUpdate);
    }
  public static void handleAfterDelete(List<Contact> deletedContacts) {
        List<Id> accountIdsToUpdate = new List<Id>();

        for (Contact deletedContact : deletedContacts) {
            accountIdsToUpdate.add(deletedContact.AccountId);
        }

        updateAccountNumbersOfContacts(accountIdsToUpdate);
    }
  private static void updateAccountNumberOfContacts(List<Id> accountIds) {
        List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

        for (Id accountId : accountIds) {
            Account acc = new Account(
                Id = accountId,
                Number_s_of_Contacts__c= [SELECT Count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]
            );
            accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
        }

        if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
            update accountsToUpdate;
        }
  }     
  }
```

Comment: Hi Sahil, Welcome. Do take much more care with formatting in future posts here though.

Comment: P.S. your logic is broken. Doing rollups are hard; you should just consider using [DLRS](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) instead. Notably, keep in mind that a user can change a contact to a new account.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a method called `updateAccountNumbersofContacts` is expected but what is implemented is `updateAccountNumberOfContacts` that is missing an `s`.

Answer (score 0):

your function name has a typo in it:

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler {
    public static void handleAfterInsert(List<Contact> newContacts) {
        List<Id> accountIdsToUpdate = new List<Id>();
        for (Contact newContact : newContacts) {
            accountIdsToUpdate.add(newContact.AccountId);
        }

        updateAccountNumberOfContacts(accountIdsToUpdate);
    }
    public static void handleAfterDelete(List<Contact> deletedContacts) {
            List<Id> accountIdsToUpdate = new List<Id>();

            for (Contact deletedContact : deletedContacts) {
                accountIdsToUpdate.add(deletedContact.AccountId);
            }

            updateAccountNumberOfContacts(accountIdsToUpdate);
        }
    private static void updateAccountNumberOfContacts(List<Id> accountIds) {
            List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

            for (Id accountId : accountIds) {
                Account acc = new Account(
                    Id = accountId,
                    Number_s_of_Contacts__c= [SELECT Count() FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :accountId]
                );
                accountsToUpdate.add(acc);
            }

            if (!accountsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                update accountsToUpdate;
            }
    }
}
```